# Laravel Service Provider - Register Parent and Child Class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not confident with this, i have 2 class

```
class Abc {
    public $hi = 'hi';

    public function __construct($xxx, $yyy) {}

    public function test() { echo 'test'; } 
}

class Def extends Abc {
    public $hi = 'hello';

    public function __construct($xxx, $yyy) {
        parent::__construct($xxx, $yyy);
    }

    public function test() { echo 'testing'; } 
}
```

And my service provider in laravel look like

```
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton('abc', function() {
            return new Abc(config('my.xxx'), config('my.yyy'));
        });

        $this->app->alias('abc', Abc::class);

        $this->app->singleton('cde', function() {
            return new Cde(config('my.xxx'), config('my.yyy'));
        });

        $this->app->alias('cde', Cde::class);
    }
}
```

This is the right way or any better implementation ?

Comment: What are the types for $xxx and $yyy? Are they primitives?

Comment: @bassxzero yes, string

Comment: If the code works then it looks fine. Based on the docs, it looks like it's what Laravel wants you to do with their framework